# Bit manipulation giving wrong output

Tags: python, c, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to make a small bit of a sudoku solver which I have in Python using C.

I'm using the same tecnhinc I did in Python, but it yields a different result. Perhaps Python is cutting some edges I don't know.

First I take a 81 chars long string and convert it to a int[9][9], like so:

```
char puzzle[] = "800000000003600000070090200050007000000045700000100030001000068008500010090000400";
int PUZZLE[9][9];

    for (int i = 0; i < 81; i++ ){
        int cur_char = puzzle[i];
        PUZZLE[row][column] = cur_char;
        column ++;
        if ((i+1)%9==0){
            column = 0;
            row ++;
        }
```

Then I do this bit manipulations to a `int ROW[9]`:

```
ROW[row] |= 1<<cur_char;
```

After going trought all the rows/columns, I can check if a number is in the row/column by doing:

```
if(ROW[i] & 1 << j) printf("ROW: %d has number: %d\n",i,j);
```

But even with a unfilled a unfilled grid, 9x9 with 0 in it. It give me this:

```
ROW: 0 has number: 1
ROW: 0 has number: 2
ROW: 0 has number: 3
ROW: 0 has number: 4
ROW: 0 has number: 6
ROW: 3 has number: 1
ROW: 3 has number: 3
ROW: 3 has number: 4
ROW: 3 has number: 5
ROW: 5 has number: 5
ROW: 5 has number: 6
ROW: 6 has number: 2
ROW: 6 has number: 6
ROW: 7 has number: 1
ROW: 7 has number: 7
ROW: 7 has number: 8
ROW: 7 has number: 9
```

Here's my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char puzzle[] = "800000000003600000070090200050007000000045700000100030001000068008500010090000400";

    int PUZZLE[9][9];

    char ROW[9];

    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;
    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < 81; i++ ){
        int cur_char = puzzle[i];
        PUZZLE[row][column] = cur_char;
        ROW[row] |= 1 << cur_char;
        column ++;
        if ((i+1)%9==0){
            column = 0;
            row ++;
        }
    }

    int j;
    for ( i = 0; i < 9; i ++) {
        for ( j = 1; j < 10; j ++) {
            if(ROW[i] & 1 << j) printf("ROW: %d has number: %d\n",i,j);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here's my Python code:

```
puzzle = "800000000003600000070090200050007000000045700000100030001000068008500010090000400"
PUZZLE = [[0]*9]*9
ROW = [0]*9
row = 0
column = 0
for i in xrange(81): # not the pythonic way, but the equivalent in C
    cur_char = int(puzzle[i])
    PUZZLE[row][column] = cur_char
    ROW[row] |= 1 << cur_char
    column += 1
    if (i+1)%9==0:
        row += 1
        column = 0

for i in xrange(9):
    for j in xrange(1,10):
        if ROW[i] & 1 << j:
            print "ROW: %d has number: %d"%(i,j)
```

My question is: **Why the C code not giving the same result as the Python; although it's the same algorithm?**

EDIT:

As pointed out, I'm now initialing char `ROW[9] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};` and also removing the extra 48 from the cur_char `int cur_char = puzzle[i] - 48;`

C yields:

```
ROW: 0 has number: 7 #wrong
ROW: 0 has number: 8 #right
ROW: 0 has number: 9 #wrong
ROW: 1 has number: 2 #wrong
ROW: 1 has number: 5 #wrong
ROW: 2 has number: 1 #wrong
ROW: 2 has number: 6 #wrong
ROW: 3 has number: 4 #wrong
ROW: 3 has number: 6 #wrong
ROW: 4 has number: 3 #wrong
ROW: 4 has number: 4 #right
ROW: 4 has number: 6 #wrong
ROW: 5 has number: 2 #wrong
ROW: 6 has number: 5 #wrong
ROW: 6 has number: 7 #wrong
ROW: 6 has number: 8 #right
ROW: 6 has number: 9 #wrong
ROW: 7 has number: 4 #wrong
ROW: 7 has number: 7 #wrong
ROW: 7 has number: 8 #right
ROW: 7 has number: 9 #wrong
ROW: 8 has number: 3 #wrong
```

Python yields:

```
ROW: 0 has number: 8
ROW: 1 has number: 3
ROW: 1 has number: 6
ROW: 2 has number: 2
ROW: 2 has number: 7
ROW: 2 has number: 9
ROW: 3 has number: 5
ROW: 3 has number: 7
ROW: 4 has number: 4
ROW: 4 has number: 5
ROW: 4 has number: 7
ROW: 5 has number: 1
ROW: 5 has number: 3
ROW: 6 has number: 1
ROW: 6 has number: 6
ROW: 6 has number: 8
ROW: 7 has number: 1
ROW: 7 has number: 5
ROW: 7 has number: 8
ROW: 8 has number: 4
ROW: 8 has number: 9
```

As you can see, it yields few of the numbers right, but misses most, and adds some others too.

Comment: Some interesting use of Python there, but what does `|=` do? It gives a SyntaxError for me (although on Python 3), and I can't find anything on it online.

Comment: It's a bitwise Equal OR. It's the same as: `ROW[row] = ROW[row] | 1 << cur_char`

Comment: You have defined ROW as a char array, but have called it an int array in other places. Which is it? You will get overflow problems with `ROW[row] |= 1 << cur_char;` when ROW is a char array and cur_char is 8 or greater.

Comment: What result does your Python code give? You said (if I understood) that even with a completely empty grid, you get results showing numbers in rows. Why not comment out the code that stores the puzzle data in ROW and make certain that when ROW is empty, you get the correct output. You will probably find that you need to initialize the elements of ROW to zero (as @Weather Vane said). Do you really want ROW to be a char array? Chars are frequently only 8 bits, you seem to need 9 places (one for each digit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, manage to make it work: Thanks to Weather Vane and Dunes. It was two mistakes.

1) I wasn't initialing the ROW and 2) I was using a char array, instead of int.

This fixed both errors:

```
int ROW[9] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

Result:

```
ROW 0 has numbers: 8
ROW 1 has numbers: 3, 6
ROW 2 has numbers: 2, 7, 9
ROW 3 has numbers: 5, 7
ROW 4 has numbers: 4, 5, 7
ROW 5 has numbers: 1, 3
ROW 6 has numbers: 1, 6, 8
ROW 7 has numbers: 1, 5, 8
ROW 8 has numbers: 4, 9
```

Comment: I marked this as a community wiki since I didn't get the answer by myself. But neither any other answer fixed both mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the line

```
ROW[row] |= 1 << cur_char;
```

I see two faults. First, `ROW[]` has not been initialised, so you are orring with uninitialised value. Secondly, the first char of the C string `puzzle[]` is '8' which is ascii 56. So shifting `1 << 56` makes no sense and is UB anyway, although I don't know how Python handles this.